# python pyserial can't establish connection to Hardware at COM port

Tags: python, pyserial

I am working on a python script to write and read data to an electronic torque wrench via a 868 MHz radio module. The radio module is connected via USB port, the communication runs via COM port. The OS is Windows 10.

In principle the communication is very simple, send a string via COM port and get back a string the same way. There is a LED lamp on the module which does flash when data is send.
I tested the communication via COM port with putty under Linux and with powershell under Windows with very low input parameters (port=COM3, bitrate=115200), it works. I can send a small string and get back the expected answer from the torque wrench. Also the LED does flash.

Powershell:

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,115200,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("819090520BAT")
$answer=$port.ReadLine()
$port.Close()
echo $answer
```

A small python script can find the hardware on the COM3 port using the serial.tools.list_ports module.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial

vid=8263
pid=1007
serial_timeout = 0.01
serial_baudrate = 115200

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if(vid == p.vid and pid == p.pid):
        com_port = Serial(port=p.device, baudrate=serial_baudrate)
        print("com_port:",com_port)
        sended = s.write(b"819090520BAT")
        print("sended:",sended)
        res = s.readline()
        print(res.decode("ASCII"))
```

When I establish the connection to the found COM3 port the returned information of the connection looks plausible. The return value of the write-function is 12, so Informations were send to the radio module.
But the LED doesn't flash and there is no answer of the module (the variable res is empty).

I tried different encodings of the string (ASCII, UTF-8) but there is no difference.

```
sended = s.write("819090520BAT".encode("ASCII"))
sended = s.write("819090520BAT".encode("UTF-8"))
```

Also reseting the buffers show no other result.

```
com_port.reset_input_buffer()
com_port.reset_output_buffer()

com_port.flushInput()
com_port.flushOutput()
```

last I have tried to change the communication parameters, but also no other reaction of the module.

xonxoff=True

rtscts=True

dsrdtr=True

Which is not surprising because these parameters were all disabled under putty and powershell.

Where is my fault? Why can putty and powershell connect and not pyserial?

Comment: In your Python code, you're not terminating the command with a newline and/or linefeed character - presumably the PowerShell `WriteLine()` is doing that for you.

Comment: Great answer! With  `sended = s.write(b"819090520BAT\n")` the LED does flash! There is still no answer from the torque wrench but the first step is done.

Comment: With a time delay of 3*timeout before reading I get an answer from the torque wrench. So my problem is solved, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great help! This is the code which works:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
import time

vid=8263
pid=1007
serial_timeout = 0.005
serial_baudrate = 115200

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if(vid == p.vid and pid == p.pid):
        com_port = Serial(port=p.device, baudrate=serial_baudrate)
        print("com_port:",com_port)
        sended = s.write(b"819090520BAT\n")
        print("sended:",sended)
        time.sleep(serial_timeout*3)
        res = s.readline()
        print(res.decode("ASCII"))
```